# Using Win7 PC for routing

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

I would like to use a Windows 7 PC with 3 Lan cards and 2 Wi-Fi as a router.

For example, I have a PC with 3 LAN cards and two Wi-Fi cards. I would like to use one LAN card to connect to the public Internet through some router, 1 Wi-Fi to connect to the public Internet through some wi-fi rounter, 2 LAN cards to share FTP (and internet from LAN) to 2 other computers and 1 Wi-Fi to create a hot-spot for sharing internet connection from LAN. Is it possible to do this using Windows 7 without installing any additional software.

I know that I can use router for this. I can't.

I know that I have option to share Network Interface data in Win7, but I want to be sure that my config will work.

All networks should be accessible on the PC acting as a router.

Comment: I am pretty sure your question would benefit a lot from some organization as now it seems more like a draft of a thought than a clearly written thought (don't take this grammar/writing nazism too hard). At the moment it is a bit unclear whether you have 3 LAN cards and 3 WLAN cards in one PC or 3 LAN/2 WAN or something else, for example. It might also be a good idea to draw a diagram of what you're trying to accomplish, using, e.g., [draw.io](http://draw.io).

Comment: @SamiLaine Thank you for editing :). I am feeling bad now :( .  I have 3LAN / 2 WAN. I'll do the drawing

Comment: How many internal subnets do you need? Does this computer really need to be windows 7, could it be something like pfsense or vyos? Is this computer's sole purpose a router or as a desktop computer too? If you are never going to use it interactively (keyboard and monitor) and want windows 7 for file sharing and routing only, I would recommend installing something like esxi, then have a windows VM for file sharing and a dedicated router vm like pfsense for routing (or vyos for routing and wifi, though it's more complex to set up).

Comment: UPDATE : there is diagramm http://i.imgur.com/2i28qba.png

Comment: @AlexBerry This is desktop PC I have to use. But I can install VMWare and install Linux over Win7, but I cannot install Win7 over Linux

Comment: @AlexBerry I really need to connect only 2 computers to my own

Comment: There exists an application called [`Virtual Router`](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) that works on Windows Vista and beyond.  I would just use that.  You won't have much control, and you might not have another option if that application doesn't do what you want, because there isn't a great deal of market for a router designed to run the Windows kernel instead of say a linux kernel

Comment: Windows 7 has very basic routing capabilities, that seem to be extendable with the above option "Virtual Router", however I really wouldn't rely on this. I think your best option would just be a cheap 5 port gigabit switch and a cheap wireless g/n access point plugged in to the switch, then you wouldn't have to worry. I'm sure the energy bill from leaving your pc on all day long will be less than the cost of a switch and an access point.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it's possible with windows, but you can try [zeroshell](http://www.zeroshell.net/)

Comment: Sure its possible. There exists an application called [`Virtual Router`](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) that works on Windows Vista and beyond.

Comment: Yes but that covers only the wifi side and not the other stuff.